# Is ./ really needed for pathing?

Tags: html, server, filepath

I'm wondering if the ./ in paths are really needed since,

```
./myfile.jpg
myfile.jpg
```

If both targets the current folder. Why are ./ sometimes used and sometimes it isn't used? Are there advantages or bugs it fixed when uploaded to a root server vs sub-domains or other reasons?

Comment: Can you tell us where these paths are being used? Sometimes `./` is necessary. Sometimes it isn't.

Comment: I'm using them in html, css imports, etc... Sometimes in root server, sometimes in sub folders as sub projects.

Just wanted to standardize everything so am wondering what are the use cases when one is needed over the other? And why?

Comment: I think that's a bit too broad of a question. Could you please edit your question to show examples of the code (HTML, etc.) where you are using `./` and someone can tell you whether it's needed in those situations.

Comment: Hi @JLRishe, thanks for your reply. But I'm not looking for specific situations, I'm looking to understand the difference between the two, so that next time when I need to link a file in the current folder, I would know which to use and why to use it over the other.

Comment: There are thousands and thousands of different situations where people use paths and nobody is going to sit here and list out every one, telling you when `./` is necessary and when it isn't. _"next time when I need to link a file in the current folder,"_ Please show me the code for "linking a file in the current folder", because that description is rather vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./` means the current working directory. You can just reference the file directly by name, without it.

```
. = This location
.. = Up a directory
```

It means that `./foo.html` is just `foo.html`. And it is optional, but it may have relevance if a script generated the path (relevance to the script that is, not how the reference works). You can omit it by the way. It’s useful only for clarity. There is no functional difference between it being there and not being there.

You can use the following list as quick reference:

```
/ = Root directory
. = This location
.. = Up a directory
./ = Current directory
../ = Parent of current directory
../../ = Two directories backwards
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm trying to understand. So there are actually no differences between them except when you are using some script that generates the path, which is why I keep seeing ./ used in webpack projects, etc.